# [<__NSCFDictionary 0x7fdf8a926250> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HName

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Hi All I have an array of dictionary from which I want to find a hotel name but keeps getting this error

> [<__NSCFDictionary 0x7fdf8a926250> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key HName.

My code is:

```
searchHotelNameString = _txtHotelSearch.text;
_resultObjectsArray = [NSArray array];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"@HName like %@",
                                      searchHotelNameString];
_resultObjectsArray = [self.arrHotelResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and my dictionary is:

```
{
    "@HIndex" = 5;
    "@HName" = "XYZ Plaza Hotel Dubai";
    "@Lattitude" = "25.2174";
}
```

Comment: The problem is your `@` prefixes (they are special characters in a predicate, so if you look at the error, the `@` has been removed from the predicate and the property name became `HName` which of course doesn't exist). If this cannot be changed (your prefixes), something like `@"self['@HName'] like %@"` would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following format string:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['@HName'] CONTAINS %@",
                              searchHotelNameString];
```

Or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['@HName'] LIKE %@",
                              [[@"*" stringByAppendingString:searchHotelNameString] stringByAppendingString:@"*"]];
```

You must add wildcards to the `searchHotelNameString` if you using `like` operator.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

---

**EDIT:**

I’d suggest to use `==` instead of using `LIKE` if you do not use regex:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['@HName'] == %@",
                              searchHotelNameString];
```

Here is my test code:

```
NSString *searchHotelNameString = @"Taj Palace";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['@HName'] == %@",
                          searchHotelNameString];

NSArray *arrHotelResults = @[
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @5, @"@HName" : @"XYZ Plaza Hotel Dubai", @"@Lattitude" : @25.2174},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @5, @"@HName" : @"Beijing", @"@Lattitude" : @25.2174},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @5, @"@HName" : @"Xiamen", @"@Lattitude" : @25.2174},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @5, @"@HName" : @"Wuhan", @"@Lattitude" : @25.2174},
                             @{@"@HIndex" : @5, @"@HName" : @"Taj Palace", @"@Lattitude" : @25.2174}
                             ];
NSArray *resultObjectsArray = [arrHotelResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", resultObjectsArray);
```

Comment: thanks its working but i have to search the same name i mean if i have to search Taj Palace then the search string should be Taj Palace if I am typing    taj palace its not showing result.

Comment: You can use `==` instead of using `LIKE`.

Comment: I have posted my test code, you can compare it with your code.

Comment: your code is working fine but it is case sensitive search taj palace instead of Taj Palace and you would not get any result

Comment: Got it. You should to use `SELF['@HName'] LIKE[cd] %@`. The `LIKE[cd]` is a modified `LIKE` operator that is case-insensitive and diacritic-insensitive.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i sort the array using the nssortdescriptor?

Comment: @Bruce You can post a new question.